# How do I populate a table without adding a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app that allows users to create events and file them in a category. While users fill in their own data for the event attributes, they must choose from a list of pre-existing categories for which their event will be filed under.

I want to hard-code these categories into the app but I'm not really sure how to do that. I'd like to do it without a controller and view so I don't have to add security features to keep users out.

These are my models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :category_id, :cost, :title, :venue
  belongs_to :category
  validates :address, :category_id, :cost, :title, :venue, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using what is called `Seeding Data`.

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
# db/seeds.rb
["Category1", "Category2", "Category3"].each do |category|
    Category.find_or_create_by_name(category)
end
```

Then from your terminal run the seeds using:

```
rake db:seed
```

Comment: This worked great and I was able to get model associations working correctly, but I'm having a bit of trouble iterating all the category names using `@categories.each do`. I get the error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". Is there another way it has to be done when using seeds.rb?

Comment: If I understand you correctly (i.e. using instance variable as such): you don't use seeds.rb as such.  I suggest you ask a new question with the details of what you are doing now and what the problem is.